# On Android, how to get a word, compare the word with each item of a spinner, and if it is the same, the spinner item is selected on the screen?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, spinner, string-comparison

On Android, how to get a word (for example Blue), compare the word with each item of a Spinner, and if the word is equal to a Spinner item (on this case, if there is blue in an Spinner item), the system automatically puts selected the item with the word on the screen, that is, on this case, the system automatically shows blue on the spinner?

Remembering what is Spinner in Android: https://dds861.medium.com/simple-spinner-874a65834422

The code to transform the selected item of a Spinner and transform into String is:

```
 <string-array name = "color">
         <item>Click here to choose your preferred color</item>
         <item>Blue</item>
         <item>Red</item>
         <item>Yellow</item>
         <item>Green</item>
     </string-array>
 
 Spinner colorField = findViewById(R.id.spinner_color); 
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =
 ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.color,
 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        colorField.setAdapter(adapter);
        colorField.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
  final String colorIntoString = colorField.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

But how to make the inverse?
It doesn't necessarily have to be in that code.
Does anyone know of any code to get a String, compare all items from a Spinner, and return the Spinner item that is equal to String?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your string array like this:

`String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color);`

Then you can compare each element with your desired string.

```
String color = "blue";
for(int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (colors[i].equals(color)) {
        colorField.setSelection(i); // sets the selection
        break;
    }
}
```